# How can I explain what this pseudo code do with simple math words?

Tags: induction, recursion

I would like to know how would you descriebe what this algorithm do ?
And would like to know how to prove my description by induction. But I think that my description is poorly formulated.

```
1: if n = 0 then
2: return 1;
3: end if
4: return n · bar(n − 1);
```

My Answer so far: The algorithm calculates recursively the input n, until it has the value 0 and returns 1.
Please give me feedback about my simple answer. What would you change?

Comment: "until" should perhaps be replaced with "unless". "until" would be more appropriate for describing a `while` loop, but here you just have a simple `if` statement. But it looks like this code is implementing the factorial function, so you can simply say it "calculates the factorial of `n` recursively, returning `0` if `n=1`".

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was beautiful and simple.